# Understand data reported in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I see in the Firebase console that my project/app/account stores 600 MB data according to Firebase but I have only three users registered. It says that this data increased from 200 MB since a couple of days, but I do not know what causes the increase. What I did last couple of days was mostly deploying new versions of the appengine app which authenticates users via Firebase. I see that there are many "small" (< 5 MB) files in this bucket which belongs to my project but I do not understand what those files are. How do they belong to my project/app/account?

`Buckets/asia.artifacts.my-app-name.appspot.com/containers/images`

My project is registered in Asia south 1 region so that is no surprise. But I want to be able to interpret what Firebase console says:

`Bytes stored
663.3 MB stored
Object count
1.3K objects
Bandwidth
745.3 MB sent
Requests
2.7K total`

Bytes stored and Object count are quite large for only three users in the user pool. How is that calculated?

This happens as part of migrating an old Python2.7 appengine app to Python3.x runtime, changing the authentication method to Firebase and a VM with Elasticsearch for the search API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, an image is not a picture but a snapshot of your deployed code with all it's dependencies installed. It seems that your configuration is holding on to older deployments.

You can manage these and delete the outdated ones from the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine).